# magento - adding BLOCKTYPE to static block

Tags: magento, plugins, block

ok so I installed a plugin. The only option to use it is to place this code in a CMS page: {{block type="ve_easyslide/list" template="ve/easyslide.phtml"}}.

firstly, what are these blocks of code called and what does it do?

secondly, how could I use this in a static block? When I try and put it in a static block now it just displays the code on ym site. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's called magic variables.
Ie
`{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`
is equivalent to layout's XML:
`<block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" />`
that you can find in catalog.xml in example.
 Type attribute points to class - in this example it's `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and template, well, points to template file :)

You can use the same code in static block but be sure to insert the code while wysiwyg editor is Off.